# PHP float bug: PHP Hangs On Numeric Value

Tags: php, floating-point, numeric

I just read an interesting article about php hanging on certain float numbers, see [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/01/04/weird_php_dos_vuln/) and [Exploring Binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/php-hangs-on-numeric-value-2-2250738585072011e-308/).

I never explicitly use floats, I use `number_format()` to clean my input and display for example prices.

Also, as far as I am aware, all input from for example forms are strings until I tell them otherwise so I am supposing that this problem does not affect me.

Am I right, or do I need to check for example Wordpress and Squirrelmail installations on my server to see if they cast anything to float? Or better, `grep` all php files on my servers for `float`?

Comment: *(reference)* http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53632

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ways to mitigate the problem:

1. Use a modern CPU. Most modern 64-bit CPUs would be immune (I actually had trouble finding host that allows to reproduce it since they tend to use more modern hardware). Amazon VMs seem to be immune too.
2. Upgrade your PHP version - 5.3.5 and 5.2.17 once released (probably today) include the fix.
3. Build with `-ffloat-store` in CFLAGS (will slow down the code).
4. Manually apply the [patch](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/Zend/zend_strtod.c?r1=266327&r2=307095&view=patch) to your code and rebuild PHP.

Looking for the code that has `float` probably won't help as `zend_strtod` is used by the engine in many string->number conversion scenarios.

P.S. this code btw is standard BSD library `strtod` code, not unique to PHP. So other projects using this code might be affected too.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually have one older server in use that is not 64-bit and migrating everything is going to be a lot of work, although it was on my to-do list already...

Comment: @jeroen: You can apply this patch: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/Zend/zend_strtod.c?r1=266327&r2=307095&view=patch

Answer (score 4):

From [hackernews](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2066352):

> This problem occurs due to IA-32's
> 80-bit floating point arithmetic. The
> simple fix: add a "-ffloat-store" flag
> to your CFLAGS.
>
> The problematic
> function, zend_strtod, seems to parse
> the mantissa (2.225...011 part) and
> the exponent (-308 part) separately,
> c> alculate the approximation of m*10^e
> and successively improve that
> approximation until the error becomes
> less than 0.5ulp. The problem is that
> this particular number causes the
> infinite loop (i.e. the iteration does
> not improve the error at all) in
> 80-bit FP, but does not in 64-bit FP.
> Since x86-64 in general uses the SSE2
> instruction set (with 64-bit FP)
> instead of the deprecated x87 it does
> not have this problem.

Comment: Indeed, check your arch before getting nervous. If affected, nag your provider to update. Scanning the input arrays should be the last resort.

Comment: @marcog Thanks, but the problem is that the *simple* fix is kind of abracadabra to me...

Comment: @jeroen `-ffloat-store` is a C compiler flag. Recompile PHP with it.

Comment: @marcog I figured as much, but that´s not something I´m familiar with (compiling php) and something I definitely don´t want to experiment with on a production server. I guess I'll have to experiment a bit first on a test server.

Comment: @mario One of my servers is affected, but I don´t see any urgent problems so far. That´s why I asked, to see if I missed something.

Comment: @jeroen Perhaps get some help on superuser?

Comment: @marcog That´s definitely where I'll go if I run into any compiling problems but it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @jeroen As far as we know no exploit is possible with it. It just clogs up Apache processes. You'll have to get active first when that happens, or simply wait for distro updates. You could however test with one of the webapp fuzzing tools and try to squeeze in the offending float through all available URL or POST parameters.

Answer (score 3):

As quick workaround, you could scan the input arrays:

```
foreach(array("_GET","_POST","_REQUEST","_COOKIES") as $G) {
    if (in_array('2.2250738585072011e-308', $$G)) {
         header("Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity");
         exit;
    }
}
```

This is sufficient, if you don't use subarrays in the input vars. It would work because it holds the float as string, the input arrays hold strings, and in_array operates in string context too.

However I haven't considered if there are other representations of that value. This is the only one that's known to work so far, but there might be more. So, updating is more advisable :|

Comment: According to `Exploring Binary` different forms of the same number all have that problem.

Comment: different forms would probably start with the same prefix, like `2.22507385850`

Answer (score 2):

As marcog said it's a floating point arithmetic bug with the x87 math. If you want to read more about it check out the GCC bug, [Link](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323)

Comment: Interesting paper on the pitfalls of floating point math, http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00128124

Answer (score 1):

searching for explicit float-casts won't help you - in php, a variable is treated as what it's used for. little example:

```
$mystring = "123.45"; //mystring is a string here
$myvalue = $mystring * 4; // mystring is a float here
                          // and there's no explicit float-cast
```

as you can see: upgrade/fix your php-installation is the only save way to avoid a dead server.

**EDIT:** to your comment:

floats really arn't that easy. even simple numbers like 0.7 or 0.8 can't be exactly stored and so it could happen that you 0.8, after some calculations, is 0.799999999789... with even more of this shit, it's just a matter of time until you get problems.

just as an example (and if you're a windows-user):

1. open the windows-calculator
2. calculate the sqare-root of 4 (should be 2)
3. substract 2 from the result (should be 0 but... woooow ;) )

this bug is in the windows-calculator since... ever - and it shows that even big companys can fail using floats, but the calculator doesn't kill your system - if such a bug *can* kill your system (like this php-bug) you'll *have to* upgrade/fix it, bar none.

Comment: Thanks, that's true of course but if all my variables are `ints` or `strings` that can be interpreted as `floats` with a maximum of 2 or 4 decimals, that should not be a problem.

Comment: @jeron: please take a look at my edit, it was too long for a comment ;)

Comment: I am definitely going to fix the problem and I am aware of the problems with `floats` in general but from what I´ve read so far it does not seem very urgent as it seems extremely unlikely that a simple calculation leads to that magic number (I´m talking prices, exchange rates, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't enough to simply search for float, as you're then looking for code that explicitly casts a variable value to a float, but you won't find any instances where the casting is implicit.

```
$d = '2.2250738585072011e-308';
$f = float($d);
```

is explicit casting, but what about code like:

```
$d = '2.2250738585072011e-308';
$f = $d + 0.1;
```

or

```
$d = '2.2250738585072011e-308';
if ($d == 0.5) {
```

I believe that this bug has also now been fixed within the latest PHP build code, although packages such as xampp are still affected.

Comment: Thanks, but as I commented on @oezi's answer, that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't patch your php installation you can use the following: [Any problems with the following work around for php bug #53632](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610651/any-problems-with-the-following-work-around-for-php-bug-53632)

It's just a temporary workaround until you can actually patch your php install

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch all possible notations of the number, substring-search must be used.

See http://www.aircraft24.com/en/info/php-float-dos-quickfix.htm for our latest workaround.